# How to fix different resolution, on desktop and laptop, issue of Javafx application

Tags: javafx

My javafx application looks a lot different on desktop than on laptop, due to some resolution issue. Following are the images showing both desktop and laptop view of my application.

**Look in Laptop**
[image]

**Look in Desktop**
[image]

Even with everything set to computed size, the look differs. Is there any easy way to make my application adopt the resolution? I want it to adopt any system and have the same look. Is there any suggestion for this?

Answer (score -1):

To make your screen to fit to the screen you can user

```
stage.setFullScreen(true);
```

Or you have to manually set the dimension of outer most HBox or VBox to fix this issue.

Comment: Setting the dimension manually means I have to keep separate versions for desktop and laptop.. and redo the same work twice. :(

Comment: Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();

Or you can use this code to get the screen height and width. Then you can set it to your HBox or VBox pane.
Else you have to use setFullScreen method. But the problem with fullScreen method is it will be exited once Esc.
So first method would be the solution I hope.